# Skipping delete confirmation in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

What is the best way to skip the delete confirmation page in the Django admin and go straight to deleting the objects?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You need to modify the admin action, see: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#actions-that-provide-intermediate-pages for a starting point.